# Why is continue inside a loop a bad idea?

Tags: loops, continue

Douglas Crockfod says that it is usually better to refactor the `continue` inside the loop.

Why is continue considered bad within a loop?

Comment: See also [Continue in nested while loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133408/continue-in-nested-while-loops). There's very little that's specific to C#, and many of the answers provided there are excellent.

Answer (score 7):

The use of `continue` would mean that you have insufficient conditions written in your `while`.

You should instead use `if` inside your `while` loop, or add the condition into the `while` loop.

Comment: +1 *This* is the (only sane) reason to avoid `continue` (*in most cases*, not all the time).

Comment: -1 Just saying "because `if` is better" does not answer the question at all.

Answer (score 4):

Using goto, break, continue, throw, or return inside the loop body can all have the un-desired effect as well. Here's another example where the loop control and the loop body are tightly interwoven. Does it write 1, 2, and 3 as before? Are you sure?

```
int value = 1;
    for (;;++value)
    {
        cout << value << endl;
        if (value != 4)
            continue;
        else
            break;
    }
```

You might be thinking that advising you not to use return statements inside loop bodies is over zealous. Do I really mean that? Yes I do. Functions that return something should do so via a single return statement at the very end of the function. Here are some practical reasons why:

[Link](http://www.jaggersoft.com/pubs/HowToWriteALoop.htm#Separation)

Disclaimer: Not my material, I have referenced back to the source

Answer (score 1):

The effect of `continue` is somehow comparable to a `goto` to the begin of the loop. It therefore makes your code more difficult to understand - like `goto`s.

Comment: -1 `if (...) { ... } ...` is somewhat comparable to a `goto` to the end of the block. Seriously, blindly disregarding anything remotely resembling a specialized case of `goto` is as harmful as eregious abuse of unfitting control structures (e.g. using `goto` when a higher-level control structure for the problem at hand exists).

Comment: @delnan There's quite a difference between conditional branching downwards and non-conditional branching upwards. If you ever read complex assembly code, you will know why. That being said, using `goto` can actually be acceptable, but only for non-conditional branching downwards. Unlike `continue`, which is broken by design, as it always branches upwards. The presence of `continue` is always an indication of a poorly written loop, every loop using it can be rewritten in a better way.