# Calculating sum of price in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble with getting the total amount of price when a list of item is selected by the `checkbox`. With this for loop, all I get is the first two dollar amount (I know it is the  `selectedTotal += (getAmount.amount + getAmount.amount)`; problem, but not sure how to fix it), I cannot get total price amount when there are more then three selected list item. `tempData` is array `var tempData = []` Help will be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
 <label class="item item-input ">
    <b class="input-label">Total Amount: </b>
    <span style="margin-left:30%;"> ${{getTotal()}} </span>
 </label>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.getTotal = function () {
    var selectedTotal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tempData.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.tempData[i].checked) {
            var getAmount = $scope.tempData[i];
            selectedTotal += (getAmount.amount + getAmount.amount);
        }
        return selectedTotal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `selectedTotal += (getAmount.amount + getAmount.amount);` (getAmount.amount twice) ?

Comment: I got it now, I remove the second getAmount.amount and then put the return selectedTotal outside of the forloop at it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put `return selectedTotal` outside the loop otherwise it will return value after every iteration of the loop.

```
$scope.getTotal = function () {
    var selectedTotal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tempData.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.tempData[i].checked) {
            var getAmount = $scope.tempData[i];
            selectedTotal += (getAmount.amount + getAmount.amount);
        }
    }
return selectedTotal;
}
```

Read here: [Return in for loop or outside loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800195/return-in-for-loop-or-outside-loop)

Answer (score 2):

Try to return selectedTotal outside of for loop.