# Equivalent of a continue statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering what the structured equivalent of a continue statement is in JavaScript? I am trying to get rid of a continue statement but not sure how. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
function Hand() {
    this.cards = new Array();

    this.addOneCard = function(card) {
        this.cards.push(card);
    }

    this.evaluateHand = function(){
        // Needs to handle two aces better
        var total1 = new Number;
        var total2 = new Number;

        for(var i in this.cards) {
            if (this.cards[i].value == "A") { 
                total1 += 1;
                total2 += 11;
                continue;
            }
            if (isNaN(this.cards[i].value * 1)) {
                total1 += 10;
                total2 += 10;
                continue;
            } 
            total1 += Number(this.cards[i].value);
            total2 += Number(this.cards[i].value);
        }
        return [total1, total2];
    };
}
```

Comment: why do you need a change? `continue` is part of the language and fits perfect for your need.

Answer (score 2):

**`continue` statement is valid in JavaScript.** You can use it as you would in any language.

After saying that, you can read this [interesting discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728757/why-are-continue-statements-bad-in-javascript) on why you might want to avoid it, and how.

Answer (score 1):

`else if` pair will help you here:

```
    for(var i in this.cards) {
        if (this.cards[i].value == "A") { 
            total1 += 1;
            total2 += 11;
        }
        else if (isNaN(this.cards[i].value * 1)) {
            total1 += 10;
            total2 += 10;
        } 
        else { 
            total1 += Number(this.cards[i].value);
            total2 += Number(this.cards[i].value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should hold true for any language and not just java script

```
function Hand() {
    this.cards = new Array();

    this.addOneCard = function(card) {
        this.cards.push(card);
    }

    this.evaluateHand = function(){
        // Needs to handle two aces better
        var total1 = new Number;
        var total2 = new Number;

        for(var i in this.cards) {
            if (this.cards[i].value == "A") { 
                total1 += 1;
                total2 += 11;
            }
            else if (isNaN(this.cards[i].value * 1)) {
                total1 += 10;
                total2 += 10;
            }
            else {
                total1 += Number(this.cards[i].value);
                total2 += Number(this.cards[i].value);
            }
        }
        return [total1, total2];
    };
}
```

Answer (score -3):

One option is:

```
this.cards.forEach(function(card) {
    if (card.value == "A") { 
        total1 += 1;
        total2 += 11;
        return;
    }
    if (isNaN(card.value * 1)) {
        total1 += 10;
        total2 += 10;
        return;
    } 
    total1 += Number(card.value);
    total2 += Number(card.value);
});
```

Apparently some people think `return` terminates everything... `return` stops the function running for the current element, making the next iteration start right away, as would do `continue`. I'm not saying this is a better option than just using `continue`, but it's definitively an alternative.

Comment: `return` ends the function, but `continue` goes on with the for loop.

Comment: `returns` ends the function in the loop and start the next iteration of the loop. Isn't it what `continue` is doing?

Comment: no, `return` terminates the function (and). no more iteration. `continue` jumps to the start of the for loop and skips the part to the end of the for loop.

Comment: this is incorrect. I suggest you open your console and run something like
`var a = []; [1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(function(i) { if (i % 2 == 0) { return; }  a.push(i); }` and see what's in `a` (hint: it's `[1, 3]`)

Comment: I agree `return` only stops the current iteration, but isn't what `continue` does? From the doc (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp), it says "The continue statement breaks one iteration (in the loop), if a specified condition occurs, and continues with the next iteration in the loop."

Comment: sure, but I'm done doing a `return` in a for loop, but within the forEach loop. Run this: https://jsfiddle.net/cbm5uL2m/1/ I agree doing a `return` in the for loop would not work. But this not what I'm suggesting

Comment: `forEach()` and `return` is certainly equivalent to `for` and `continue`, but I got the impression the OP wants to avoid jumping out of the middle like that. (Not sure if it is the OP's goal, but I know some people believe that a function should be structured with a single return at the end and no jumping statements like `continue` or `break` - I disagree with those people.)

Comment: :) I similarly think that returning asap helps lower the cognitive charge of remembering what nested condition you're in. Anyway thanks for confirming the obvious on `forEach + return == for + continue` !