# In C, why expression(Statement) containing comma(,) operator work differently

Tags: c, operators, operator-keyword, comma-operator

I have a simple C code and big confusion about expressions containing comma(,) operator(s).

```
int main(){
    int i=0,j=11,c;
    c=i=j,++i;
    printf("c=%d i=%d\n",c,i);
    c=(i=j,++i);
    printf("c=%d i=%d\n",c,i);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code prints:

```
c=11 i=12
c=12 i=12
```

My questions are:

1. What is the actual work of comma(,) as an operator?
2. `++` has more precedence than `,` and `=`, why evaluation is done for the expression on left of comma?
3. What will be the order if an expression contains operators with different priority, will it depend on comma(,)?
4. Is it behaving like a substitute of semicolon(;)?

Comment: I'm not an expert but this `c=i=j,++i` looks like U.B.

Comment: @MargaretBloom No, the comma operator introduces a sequence point, IIRC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087026/effect-of-using-a-comma-instead-of-a-semi-colon-in-c-and-c

Comment: It's about side effect

Comment: In short: `c=i=j,++i;` may compile and work but is not "normal" style of programming. The normal way is using `;` in place of `,`.

Comment: @CoolGuy: But the sequence point is between the evaluation of `j` and `++i`, not at the end of the whole comma expression, `(j, ++i)`, no?

Comment: @MOehm Isn't it parsed as `((c=i=j),(++i))` and not `(c=(i=(j,++i)))` due to operator precedence?

Comment: See [Uses of the Comma Operator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator#Uses)

Comment: In addition to other comments and answers: don't program like this other than for playing around, it's unreadable and pointless.

Comment: For gods sake man, whitespace isn't in short supply.

Comment: @CoolGuy: Yes, of course, I've missed that the comma operator has the highest precedence.

Comment: @MOehm Rather, it has the lowest precedence.

Comment: Yeah,, it's not UB, it's merely absolute rubbish code that woud only ever appear in homework.

Comment: Four upvotes for an obvious homework dump.  Great.

Comment: @MartinJames I've seen very similar production code when maintaining old crap. Just because it is crap code doesn't make the question bad. It is important for decent answers to point out that you shouldn't write code like this though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the comma operator , do in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The assignment operator has a higher priority then the comma operator.
Thus expression

```
c = i = j, ++i;
```

is equivalent to

```
( c = i = j ), ++i;
```

According to the C Standard (6.5.17 Comma operator)

> 2 The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void
>   expression; **there is a sequence point** between its evaluation and that
>   of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result
>   has its type and value.114)

In the expression above the result of the comma operator is discarded but it has a side effect of increasing `i`.

In this expression

```
c = ( i = j, ++i );
```

due to using parentheses you changed the order of the evaluation of the above expression. Now it is equivalent to

```
c = ( ( i = j ), ++i );
```

and variable `c` gets the value of expression `++i` according to the quote from the C Standard listed above.

Answer (score 4):

operator comma is to execute many statement and return only result of last statement.

So for `c=i=j,++i;` : `c=i=j` is executed, then `++i` and after that result of `++i` is returned (but not used).

And for `c=(i=j,++i);`, according to operator precedence, `i=j` is executed, and just after `++i` is executed, and then affectation to `c` of result of `(i=j, ++i)`, which is the result of last statement, i.e. `++i`

So, the behavior of comma is not really same as semicolon. You can use it as a substitute like in `c=i=j,++i;`.

Personally, I do not encourage to use this operator, which generates less readable and less maintainable code

Comment: ++i is done after i=j for the given statement c=(i=j,++i);

Comment: @skyconfusion sorry, bad english, of course is that, I edit my answer

Comment: Can someone explain to me why my answer is downvoted please ?

Comment: @Garf365 It seems that all answers were down-voted including mine.:)

Answer (score 2):

> What is the actual work of comma(,) as an operator?

The comma operator is mainly a superfluous feature. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c) for a description of how it works.

> ++ has more precedence than , and =, why evaluation is done for the expression on left of comma?
>      What will be the order if an expression contains operators with different priority, will it depend on comma(,)?

The left operand is evaluated for side effects. The result of the comma operator is the result of the evaluated right operand. Note that the comma operator has the lowest precedence of all operators in C.

> Is it behaving like a substitute of semicolon(;)?

Kind of, yeah. Both a semi-colon and the comma operator includes a sequence point. The difference is that the comma operator isn't the end of a statement, so it can be squeezed in with other operators on the same line, and it also returns a result.

There is really no reason why you ever would want to do this though. The main use of the comma operator is to obfuscate code, it should be avoided. The only reason why you need to learn how it works, is because you might encounter crap code containing it.

For example, your nonsense code should be rewritten into something more readable and safe:

```
int main(){
    int i=0;
    int j=11;
    int c;

    i=j;
    c=j;
    i++;
    printf("c=%d i=%d\n",c,i);

    i=j;
    i++;
    c=i;
    printf("c=%d i=%d\n",c,i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `// i=j; // superfluous, we already did this, why do it again?` isn't correct as there is an `i++` above, so actually you would end up with `c=11, i=12` followed by `c=13, i=13`

Comment: @NeilTwist Ah yeah, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Well let's split it. In the first case c and i take the value of j => c=i=j=11; then you increment i => i=12; So the code is equivalent to this

```
c = j;
i = j;
++i;
```

For the second case i takes the value of j => i=j=11 and then you increment i => i=12 and then c takes the value of i => c = 12;

So the code is equivalent to this:

```
i = j;
++i;
c = i;
```

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator will *evaluate* and *discard* all operations, up to, *but not including*, the *final* operation. This allows any number of non-consequential operations to be invoked together on a single line where only the last operation is of interest.

Think of it this way, if you have a number of loop variables to increment at any one location in a loop, you can separate all the additions/subtraction, etc.. over their own individual variables on separate line, but why? Where they are executed (within reason) is of *no-consequence* to the operation of the code. They then can be invoked on a single line with no adverse effect to the code.

Comment: The comma operator only has 2 operands, so it will simply discard the result of the left operand and use the result of the right one. The right one is always the final one.

Comment: "They then can be invoked on a single line with no adverse effect to the code." Nope, they really can't. This code `for (int i=0, int j=0, int k=0; i<something; i++, j++, k++){}` is __less__ readable than `int j=0, int k=0; for (int i=0; i<something; i++) { /* ... */  j++; k++;}` because the former is a non-trivial for loop (which is always bad programming practice), and implies that you can have more than 1 loop iterator in a loop, which doesn't make any sense. The need of writing obscure loops like this usually originates from poor program design in the first place.

Comment: @Lundin Nonsense. Of course you can have more than one loop iterator in a loop. C is not BASIC, and loop iterators don't have a special status; the for loop just has the three horns. Your second example code will go wrong if you want to use `continue`, and it gives `j` and `k` an unnecessarily large scope.

Comment: @DanHulme Umm... `continue` is another, unrelated of example of much worse programming practice. Its presence is a certain indication of poor program design and spaghetti programming. You kind of lost all credibility just for bringing that up as something you would like to use. If you want to reduce scope of the variables, then use a function. Loop iterators _do_ have special status, as there is a de facto standard rule saying that for loops should be kept simple, as close to the canonical `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)` as possible, which gives the best readability as well as the fastest code.

Comment: All of the above isn't just some personal opinions, it is industry de facto. Check for example MISRA-C, CERT C etc. Also [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913981/why-is-continue-inside-a-loop-a-bad-idea).

Comment: Isn't "industry de facto" the same thing as saying it's your opinion? MISRA is applicable to a small subset of C programs; for larger projects it's a huge limit on scalability.