# Why is i++ "unreachable code"?

Tags: c#, loops, visual-studio

**EDIT**

I'm leaving this up here, even though it makes me look stupid, because it's a subtle bug that can bite you if you're working late at night and not paying attention. Kudos to Visual Studio for having such an intelligent parser.

Basically I missed that I have nested loops, so the `continue` statement is essentially worthless here because it is continuing the `foreach` loop, not the `for` loop.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm running a search on a workbook, looking for the sheet that matches all the string search criteria. In the Visual Studio editor, the `i++` is underlined as "unreachable code".

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds the first sheet that has cells that match all the criteria.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="wb"></param>
/// <param name="searches"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static ISheet FindSheet( this IWorkbook wb, params string[] searches )
{
    if( null == wb || null == searches )
        return null;

    for( int i = 0; i < wb.NumberOfSheets; i++ )
    {
        var sheet = wb.GetSheetAt( i );
        foreach( var search in searches )
        {
            var cell = sheet.FindCell( search );
            if( null == cell )
                continue;
        }

        return sheet;
    }

    return null;
}
```

I would think that the `continue` statement has a clear meaning here: "If any of the search criteria return a `null` cell, continue to the next iteration. Otherwise, just return the sheet found in this iteration."

**CORRECTED CODE WITH NO CONTINUE STATEMENT**

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds the first sheet that has cells that match all the criteria.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="wb"></param>
/// <param name="searches"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static ISheet FindSheet( this IWorkbook wb, params string[] searches )
{
    if( null == wb || null == searches )
        return null;

    for( int i = 0; i < wb.NumberOfSheets; i++ )
    {
        var sheet = wb.GetSheetAt( i );
        if( searches.All( s => null != sheet.FindCell( s ) ) )
            return sheet;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is off-topic for CodeReview, but, the continue continues the `foreach` loop, not the `for` loop ... just saying, and now voting to close

Comment: The `return sheet;` statement always prevents it reaching the end of the `for` loop.

Comment: Why the Yoda conditions?

Comment: Hey Bruce.... welcome to CodeReview. When you add a label to your loops and use it on the continue... why don't you bring the code back for review? Seems there are a few things we can suggest.... ;-)

Comment: No, it is not... [The target of a continue statement is the end point of the embedded statement of the nearest enclosing while, do, for, or foreach statement. If a continue statement is not enclosed by a while, do, for, or foreach statement, a compile-time error occurs.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664757%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: @BrucePierson Clarification: The continue stops execution and continues to the top of the containing loop.

Comment: are you using `NPOI` ?

Comment: Yes, this is a library of extension methods for NPOI, for some ETL stuff.

Comment: @retailcoder - got the Yoda conditions reference, I finally did. Goes back to the day when you could accidentally do `x = null` (another subtle bug), it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, your for loop in completely useless. After the first iteration, it will just return no matter what. Sure your foreach loop has a `continue` statement, but this only applies to the `foreach` loop. This is why your code is unreachable.

Because of this, only the first sheet will be analysed. If this is what you want, you can simply remove the `for` loop and target the Worksheet at index 0, or you need to reaarange your loop.

Comment: Because the nearest loop from the continue statement is the `foreach` loop. In Java, he could have named the loop and could have specified which he wanted to continue, but you can't do it in C#.

Comment: Thanks. I posted an edit while you were answering. I marked this as the answer.

Comment: It's by making this kind of mistakes taht you learn the mechanics of a language. Don't worry, we've all been there. ^^

Answer (score 3):

Eric Lippert has [an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133520/1945651) and [a blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2010/01/11/continuing-to-an-outer-loop/) on what you can do when you want to continue an outer loop when you're in an inner loop.

The technique he has marked as "awesome" is to get rid of all of the loops when it's possible to do so, and indeed I believe it is possible here:

```
public static ISheet FindSheet( this IWorkbook wb, params string[] searches )
{
    if( null == wb || null == searches ) { return null; }

    return wb.FirstOrDefault(sh => searches.All(sr => sh.FindCell(sr) != null));
}
```

Comment: Nice. I only just now realized that `IWorkbook` is also `IEnumerable<ISheet>` so this is a good solution.

Comment: And I just now realized that your method has precisely the same purpose as Eric's example. :)